# Convert a list of lists of rules to a list of values

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of the following form:

```
thisVeryExcitingList={{x->1},{x->2},{x->3}}
```

I would like to convert it to the form

```
thisMoreExcitingList={1,2,3}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: `thisVeryExcitingList[[All, 1, 2]]`

Comment: x /. {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3}}

Answer (score 4):

No idea if it's optimum, but:

```
mylist = {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3}};
mylist /. Rule -> (#2 &) // Flatten
(* {1,2,3} *)
```

It helps a bit if you take a look at the full form of your expression:

```
FullForm[mylist]
(* List[List[Rule[x, 1]], List[Rule[x, 2]], List[Rule[x, 3]]] *)
```

So the code above replaces 'Rule' with the unnamed function (#2&). It helps if you write:

```
Clear[f];
mylist /. Rule -> f
(* {{f[x, 1], f[x, 2], f[x, 3]}} *)
```

Now, it is a bit easier to see that if I replace `f` with a function that returns its 2nd argument, like what `(#2&)` does, I can extract the values.

***Pickett's answers***

**First**:

```
myList[[All,1,2]]
```

With `mylist[[All,1,2]]` you can directly extract the deeply nested values from your list. Play first by writing `mylist[[All,1]]` and see what you get, then `mylist[[All,1,1]]`and, finally, the correct `mylist[[All,1,2]]`.

**Second answer**:

```
Last @@@ myList
```

You can see how this construct works, if you write the following:

```
Clear[f];
f@@@mylist
(* {f[x -> 1], f[x -> 2], f[x -> 3]} *)
```

Now it becomes obvious that if you replace `f` with `Last` you will get the desired values.

**Third answer**:

```
myList /. {Rule[_,v_]} :> v
```

You can read this code as "match all Lists of Rule's of any lhs and replace them with their respective rhs". If you write `mylist /. Rule[_, v_] :> v` it will replace the rules and not the list of rules, so you will get a result like `{{1},{2},{3}}`, because `List[List[Rule[x, 1]], List[Rule[x, 2]], List[Rule[x, 3]]]` has become `List[List[1], List[2], List[3]]`. Thus, you will need to `Flatten` it. But if you include the braces {}, there's no need to flatten.

Comment: `myList[[All,1,2]]`, `Last @@@ myList` and `myList /. {Rule[_,v_]} :> v` are all preferable.

Comment: Thanks @Pickett! Would you like to post them as answers ? They are definitely better to the eye (can't judge on the rest of the aspects).

Comment: I was hoping you would include them in your answer,  +1.

Answer (score 3):

`Values` works on both associations and a list of rules.

```
Flatten@Values[thisVeryExcitingList]
(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

You need to `Flatten` to remove the nesting from your original list.

Hope this helps.